# Custom error with Parse.com Cloud Code (server) and iOS (client)

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I have a Parse Cloud Code written in JavaScript, I have an code-based system so I have 3 different modes:

- Code is found and have't been used before - SUCCESS
- Code is found and have been used before - ERROR
- Code isn't found - ERROR

Now, when the client (iOS) gets the success - everything works fine and the code is OK. But I want to determinate between the 2 errors I have and tell the user what's wrong (your code isn't available anymore/code not found), but the error code Parse sends is always `141`, so I don't know which message should I print to the user.

How can I change the error code of the error/another way to detect what error is it on client/server side?

Thank you!

Comment: status code should be different based on what's the error, isn't it?

Comment: @AhmadF Yes, probably. But Parse doesn't let you change the `141` status code

Comment: You might need to pass an extra parameter (let's say errorCode) to be able to recognize what is the error.

Answer (score -1):

From https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#error-codes:

ScriptFailed    141 Cloud Code script failed. Usually points to a JavaScript error. Check error message for more details.

FunctionNotFound    141 Cloud function not found. Check that the specified Cloud function is present in your Cloud Code script and has been deployed.

JobNotFound 141 Background job not found. Check that the specified job is present in your Cloud Code script and has been deployed.

SuccessErrorNotCalled   141 success/error was not called. A cloud function will return once response.success() or response.error() is called. A background job will similarly finish execution once status.success() or status.error() is called. If a function or job never reaches either of the success/error methods, this error will be returned. This may happen when a function does not handle an error response correctly, preventing code execution from reaching the success() method call.

MultupleSuccessErrorCalls   141 Can’t call success/error multiple times. A cloud function will return once response.success() or response.error() is called. A background job will similarly finish execution once status.success() or status.error() is called. If a function or job calls success() and/or error() more than once in a single execution path, this error will be returned.

So looking above, you could have a Javascript error occurring during the function's run.  You could be spelling the function name wrong when calling.  You could forget to call response.success() to properly close the function.  Or you could be calling response.success() / response.error() too many times, make sure that as you follow your code's logic, you only hit one of these for every path.

If you could post the code for your Cloud Code, we might be able to further help you.